# The Finishing Step to Showing that $1/(1-4x)^{1/2}$ generates the sequence $\binom{2r}{r}$

Tags: generating-functions

**The Full Question:**

Show that $(1-4x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ generates the sequence $\binom{2n}{n}$, $n\in 
\mathbb N$

**My Research**

[How to show that $1 \over \sqrt{1 - 4x} $ generate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}x^n $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205898/how-to-show-that-1-over-sqrt1-4x-generate-sum-n-0-infty-binom2n)

[Show $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n \choose n}x^n=(1-4x)^{-1/2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69270/show-sum-limits-n-0-infty2n-choose-nxn-1-4x-1-2)

Both these questions seem similar, but I found they used a very different approach (more calculus based) to find their answers whereas my question requires me to use more algebra and definitions to get the answer.

**My Work**

1) Let $y = -4x$

2) We know the $r^{th}$ term of$(1-y)^{-1/2}$ will have the coefficient of $\binom{-1/2}{r}(-4^r)$

3) $\binom{-1/2}{r}(-4^r) = \frac{(-1/2)(-1/2-1)(-1/2-2)\cdots(-1/2-r+1)}{r!}(-4)^r$

4) If we factor out $(-1/2)$ from the whole thing, we have: $\frac{(1)(1+2)(1+4)\cdots(1+2r-2)}{r!}(2^r)=\frac{(2r-1)(2r-3)\cdots(5)(3)(1)}{r!}2^r$

5) If we multiply top and bottom by $r!$ we get:$\frac{(2r-1)(2r-3)\cdots(5)(3)(1)2^rr!}{r!r!}$

6) All that remains is to show the numerator to equal $(2r)!$ and I'm golden, however I don't really know how to do this.

**My Question**

Can anyone help me with step 6? I feel I'm very close but haven't quite been able to see it.

Comment: Nevermind, I see that $2^r$ will make up for all the evens we are missing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** Avoiding a small calculation error in OPs work in 4.) and considering a small trick in 6.) will close the gap. Here's a calculation:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{r}
> &=\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}-1\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}-2\right)\cdot\ldots\cdot
> \left(-\frac{1}{2}-(r-1)\right)}{r!}\\
> &=\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{5}{2}\right)\cdot\ldots\cdot
> \left(-\frac{2r-1}{2}\right)}{r!}\\
> &=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^r\cdot\frac{(2r-1)(2r-3)\cdot\ldots\cdot5\cdot3\cdot1}{r!}\tag{1}\\
> &=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^r\cdot\frac{(2r)(2r-1)(2r-2)(2r-3)\cdot\ldots\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}
> {r!(2r)(2r-2)(2r-4)\cdot\ldots\cdot4\cdot2}\tag{2}\\
> &=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^r\cdot\frac{(2r)!}
> {r!2^r\cdot r(r-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot2\cdot1}\\
> &=\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^r\frac{(2r)!}{r!r!}\\
> &=\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^r\binom{2r}{r}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we factor out $\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^r$. Please note that $2^r$ is part of the *denominator* (check corr. part (4) in your calculation)
- In (2) we *fill in even factors* to complete the numerator to $(2r)!$ and we also write these factors in the denominator as compensation.

> **Clever notation:** In (1) it's convenient to use the compact notation of *[double factorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)*.We observe
>   $$(2r)!=(2r)!!(2r-1)!!=2^rr!(2r-1)!!$$
>   and using this notation in (1):
>
> \begin{align*}
> \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{r}
> &=\ldots\\
> &=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^r\frac{(2r-1)!!}{r!}\\
> &=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^r\frac{(2r)!}{r!(2r)!!}\\
> &=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^r\frac{(2r)!}{r!2^rr!}\\
> &=\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^r\binom{2r}{r}\\
> \end{align*}