# Evaluate a series with binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, binomial-coefficients

> If 
>   $$y=\frac{3}{5}+\frac{1\cdot 3}{2!}(\frac{2}{5})^2+\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{3!}(\frac{2}{5})^3+\dots$$
>   Then find the value 0f $y^2+2y$.

My approach is as follow
$$y-\frac{1}{5}=\frac{2}{5}+\frac{1\cdot 3}{2!}(\frac{2}{5})^2+\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{3!}(\frac{2}{5})^3+\dots$$

Let $x=\frac{2}{5}$, $Y=y-\frac{1}{5}$. Then
$$Y=x+\frac{1\cdot 3}{2!}(x)^2+\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{3!}(x)^3+\dots$$
I am not able to proceed from here.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Recall the definition of [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial), 
$$1\cdot 3\cdots (2k-1)=\frac{k!}{2^k}\binom{2k}{k}.$$
Hence
$$Y=x+\frac{1\cdot 3}{2!}(x)^2+\frac{1\cdot 3 \cdot 5}{3!}(x)^3+\dots=
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k}(x/2)^k.$$
Now take a look at [How to show that $1 \over \sqrt{1 - 4x} $ generate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}x^n $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205898/how-to-show-that-1-over-sqrt1-4x-generate-sum-n-0-infty-binom2n) .