# Find the convergence radius of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}}z^n$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I need to find the convergence radius of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}}z^n
$$
I proceeded like this:
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{(2n+2)!}{((n+1)!)^2}}z^{n+1} \times {\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}}
$$
But I don't see how to proceed further.

Comment: ${2n \choose n} \asymp \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{n}}$, so I'd guess $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: ratio test${}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost started with the idea but not finished.
$$a_n={\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}}\implies \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{n+1}{4 n+2}\implies R=\frac 14$$

Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) in particular paragraph entitled *Theoretical radius*.

Comment: how did you get ${\frac{n+1}{4n+2}}$?

Comment: @user3132457. Just simplifying the factorials.

Comment: how? I couldn't

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}}z^n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}.$$
The nearest point to the origin such that it is not analytic is $z=\frac14$. Therefore the radius of convergence is $\frac14$.

Comment: how do you get this equality?

Comment: @user3132457 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205898/how-to-show-that-1-over-sqrt1-4x-generate-sum-n-0-infty-binom2n